# How are timestamps deemed invalid?

Tags: transactions, consensus, scp

The Stellar Consensus Protocol orders block candidates (via ballots) by the maximum timestamp and union of their transactions. It says that "values [transactions/ballots] with invalid timestamps will not receive enough nominations".

What makes a timestamp invalid? Is there a range relative to a node's own clock it must be in?

Do nodes sync their clocks with each other, or do they sync through other means (like NTP)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the stellar-core codebase, under the [HerderSCPDriver's validateValueHelper function](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/33bfdea049db3a7a0170bfbb45af2764290e9232/src/herder/HerderSCPDriver.cpp), there is this code snippet:

```
    // Check closeTime (not too old)
    if (b.closeTime <= lastCloseTime)
    {
        return SCPDriver::kInvalidValue;
    }

    // Check closeTime (not too far in future)
    uint64_t timeNow = mApp.timeNow();
    if (b.closeTime > timeNow + Herder::MAX_TIME_SLIP_SECONDS.count())
    {
        return SCPDriver::kInvalidValue;
    }
```

And in [herder](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/3c1b98e5420f038381850f7746e0634b8274bbda/src/herder/Herder.cpp), I see that:

```
std::chrono::seconds const Herder::MAX_TIME_SLIP_SECONDS(60);
```

So I believe if a timestamp is less than the previous close time, or the timestamp is a minute ahead (a hard coded value) then the timestamp is deemed invalid.

And to answer your second question, there is a [NTP sync check](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/f796b0850b7cd0b36bc881cdb679ed3aceaca626/src/main/NtpSynchronizationChecker.cpp). The role of this is, according to the [this file](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/f796b0850b7cd0b36bc881cdb679ed3aceaca626/src/main/NtpSynchronizationChecker.h):

> [To] periodically check if local time is synchronized with
>   NTP server.