# How can Stellar timestamps be manipulated, and how accurate are they in practice?

Tags: stellar-core, transactions, security

Stellar can be used for [Trusted timestamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) via e.g. the [STELLARAPI.IO](https://stellarapi.io/).

As described here at [How are timestamps deemed invalid?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/632/how-are-timestamps-deemed-invalid) it seems that the code enforces two checks on timestamps:

- monotonicity: the `close_time` of each block must be greater than the previous `close_time`
- accuracy: the `close_time` must be no more than MAX_TIME_SLIP_SECONDS (hardcoded as 60) in the future, as determined by a quorum of nodes (I guess)

But about how accurate are Stellar timestamps in practice? Is the standard deviation 10 seconds? 1 second? How far off could a clever adversary manipulate it? 60 seconds?

Part of the rationale for this question is to evaluate Stellar as a simple, essentially free source of trusted timestamps and commitments to hashes which is much more accurate and convenient than e.g. Bitcoin, as discussed at

- [Trusted timestamping - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping#Decentralized_timestamping_on_the_blockchain)

Here are some more specific, but perhaps still loosely-defined questions.

- How often do the Stellar checks fail in real life?
- How often do proposed blocks have anything like a `close_time` 60 seconds in the future? I'd guess you could find possible times like that by looking for times when the gap between blocks was unusually large, since I guess the whole system would hang out until that future point in time arrived.
- Is there a source of statistics like that, or an easy way to query or download the full blockchain to calculate those statistics?
- Typically, in practice, how far off are timestamps of proposed blocks, as judged by a node that keeps very good time?